# Reading data using windows-1252 file encoding

Tags: python, r

What does it mean to read data using windows-1252 file encoding? How can we do its equivalent in R?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to encode characters. Nowadays, it's most of the time utf-8 which is compatible to most characters. You can read up here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding You did not specify what kind of data you want to read in, so it's hard to tell you how to do it in R. If you want to read in tabular data, e.g. from a csv, you can use the read.table family of functions with the fileEncoding option, further details here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html
If you want to read or set the encoding of a specific character vector, use this function: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html